# how to replace word to word in my code in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var input = 'How i change bad 1 bad 2 bad 3'; 
var word  = input.split(' ').map(function(item){
   return item.includes("bad");
})
console.log(word);
```

I stuck in my code ... How to change bad word to good word

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: `input.replace(/bad/g, 'good');`

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript String `replace()` Method.

If you are replacing a value only the first instance of the value.

```
var input = 'How i change bad 1 bad 2 bad 3';
input = str.replace("bad", "good");
console.log(input);

// Output: How i change good bad 2 bad 3
```

To replace all occurrences of a specified value, use the global (g) modifier

```
var input = 'How i change bad 1 bad 2 bad 3';
input = str.replace(/bad/g, "good");
console.log(input);

// Output: How i change good good 2 good 3
```

Perform a global, case-insensitive replacement:

```
var input = 'How i change Bad 1 bad 2 bad 3';
input = str.replace(/bad/gi, "good");
console.log(input);

// Output: How i change good good 2 good 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other person linked to, you should read up on the `replace` function. Specifically, it allows you to provide a regular expression to match against, and you can provide a flag to tell it to search and replace all instances of the match.

replace:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Regular Expressions:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions