# Replacing text in an input box of a webpage

Tags: javascript

I wanted to replace a particular text "Dog" in an input box of a webpage to the text "Cat". I am new to jaavascript, so please pardon me for asking this question if I happen to break any forum rules.
Thank you in advance. Vicky.

Comment: Would be cool if you posted some of your relevant code when you ask a question in here and your attempts to solve the problem, otherwise some ppl might get pissed thinking that you just want them to solve the work for you. By doing that we can see what's your current understanding of the problem at hand and help you get there :)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum, it is more like a dictionary. It seems like you might be asking about two separate things that are already answered. [Here is an answer that explains how to set an input value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7609144/2647442) and [here is an answer that explains how to replace text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60836282/2647442)

Answer (score 0):

You can get an element by it's id and then change it's value

`document.getElementById("nameofid").value = "Cat";`

Answer (score 0):

you can use replace() function fot that.

```js
const ta = document.querySelector("textarea");

const str = ta.value.replace("dog","cat");
ta.value = str
console.log(ta.value,"change to" ,str)
```

```html
<textarea>a little dog.</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying I used the document.querySelectorAll for this problem. But isnt workig. const ta = document.querySelectorAll("[id$='txtValue']"); const str = ta.value.replace("dog","cat"); ta.value = str console.log(ta.value,"change to" ,str)

Comment: You welcome! Do you have multiple textaraes? If you using querySelectorAll you will get a collection of nodes. Means that you must iterate this collection.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to:

1. Search for the word "Dog" in all inputs on the page.
2. Replace each "Dog" with "Cat"

So, let's simplify it.

1. Use the `querySelectorAll` to select all the inputs on the page and store them in a `inputs` variable:

   ```js
   const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
   ```
2. Use a `forEach` loop to iterate through each `input` in the `inputs`, within the loop, access the value of each input using the `.value` property. And then use the built-in `replace()` function to replace each "Dog" with "Cat":

   ```js
   inputs.forEach(input => {
       input.value = input.value.replace("Dog", "Cat");
   });
   ```
3. However, in the previous code, there is a potential problem. When there is another word containing "Dog", it will also be replaced, for example, "notDog" becoming "notCat". And to prevent this, use a regular expression:

   ```js
   input.value = input.value.replace(/\bDog\b/, "Cat"); // Replace only when "Dog" words stand alone
   ```

```js
const button = document.querySelector("[data-button]");
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.value = input.value.replace(/\bDog\b/, "Cat");
  });
});
```

```html
<button data-button>Replace Standalone Dog with Cat</button>
<input type="text" value="Dog 1 example">
<input type="text" value="Dog 2 example">
<input type="text" value="Dog 4 example">
<input type="text" value="notDog">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Change input box to Cat</h2>
<div id="inputBoxId">Dog</div>
<script>
 document.getElementById("inputBoxId").innerHTML = "Cat";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```